# Strategy for calculating possible paths between objects (with possibility for infinity) in swing?

Tags: java, swing, vector

I'm trying to build a logic function for my map building application that will tell me if there is an available path from one swing object to another.

Specifically I want to identify all the possible paths from one Jabel to another Jlabel.

Empty space is denoted by a white image, a wall is denoted as a blue image, player start is orange, and player finish is green.

So what I think I want to do is check each available path from the starting point. If the path ends at the goal return true, if it ends at a wall then make that the new starting path. My current Idea is to create a 2d array that populates with ints 0. When a the  user changes a tile to something other than white, a corresponding spot in the array will change to 1 2 or 3 depending on what tile they placed. Then when they try to save the map the algorithm would use that 2d array to represent the map and check adjacent and linear paths.

Am I on the right track with this or is it more complicated?

I feel like this could turn out to be very slow(like n^2 or worse) if it's a complicated map because the paths can branch out. I'm thinking about using a sort of Dijkestras method for solving this, but I also don't know how exactly I would do that in swing.

There are some movement restrictions in the game as well.

- You can't change directions unless you are stopped.
- You can't stop unless you hit a wall or the edge of the map.

This eliminates a few options to sift through, as the number of paths become alot more limited.

[image: Make sure there is at least one way for orange to get to green.]

Comment: I'm no expert on algorithms and so can't comment directly on your question, but I can state without a doubt that the problem is mainly algorithmic, and has nothing to do with Swing, since that's just the rendering library, and in fact little to do with Java. Again the algorithm is the entire issue.

Comment: Yeah, i kind of thought that but i also wanted to make sure people know im using swing in case there's a special tool im unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you are on the right path.. You can use something like this for collision:

In which you made a object, class Coordinate

```js
constructor(){
  block = new Coordinate[length];
  path = new Coordinate[length];

for (int i=0;i<number_of_blocks;i++){
  if (block[i].x==path[length_of_path].x && block[i].y==path[length_of_path].y){
    //now you have a collision so go back
    }
  
  or
  
for (int i=0;i<number_of_blocks;i++){
  if (block[i].x==path[length_of_path].x+1 && block[i].y==path[length_of_path].y){
    //now you know you have a block on the right side
    }
```

In which you have to make a object for, class Coordinate for example, to help store the coordinates.

```js
class Coordinate {
  
 int x,y;
  
 Coordinate() {
  x=0;
  y=0;
 }
 
 Coordinate(int x, int y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
}
```

This way you can easily check if there is a collision or not and if you're out of bounds. Then you change direction adding a new coordinate to you string with the new coordinates and so on. I think this is easier then using 2d Arrays.

If you're array is out of options you go back till there is another direction possible and go that way. (You only have to save seperatly what your previous coordinates were and overwrite them while you go back).

GL